# How to iterate customised Json data with its UserID in Python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I want to build a customised Json with values **x** & **y**. and I want to iterate it through its **userID** 
(imagine that, **x** & **y** are some calculated variables)

for example:
**Input Data**

```
[
  {
    "userID": "1acv",
    "debit": 2000,
    "Balance": 15000,
    "date": "2018-03-28"
  },
  {
    "userID": "1acv",
    "debit": 1000,
    "Balance": 14000,
    "date": "2018-03-29"
  },
  {
    "userID": "1acv",
    "debit": 5000,
    "Balance": 9000,
    "date": "2018-03-30"
  },
  {
    "userID": "2acv",
    "debit": 500,
    "Balance": 5000,
    "date": "2018-02-03"
  },
  {
    "userID": "2acv",
    "debit": 1500,
    "Balance": 3500,
    "date": "2018-02-03"
  },
  {
    "userID": "2acv",
    "debit": 500,
    "Balance": 3000,
    "date": "2018-02-03"
  }
]
```

**Code**

```
with open('/path/data.json', 'r') as f:
    reader = json.load(f)
#Calculation is done to find the values x and y
js = {
     "UserID": userID,
     "Total Debit": x,
     "Avg Debit": y
     }
with open('/path/test.json', 'w') as outfile:
     json.dump(js, outfile)
```

**Expected Json Output:**

I want to calculate the sum of debits and average of debits for each userID

```
[
{"userID": "1acv", "Total Debits": 8000,"Avg Debit": 2666.6666},
{"userID": "2acv", "Total Debits": 2500,"Avg Debit": 833.3333}
]
```

**PS:** I'm okay with both Json or Csv Output

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way using `collections.defaultdict()`:

```
In [21]: from collections import defaultdict

In [22]: d = defaultdict(list)

In [23]: for i in js:
    ...:     d[i['userID']].append(i['debit'])
    ...:     
    ...: 

In [24]: 
    ...: [{"userID": "1acv", "Total Debits": sum(debits),"Avg Debit": sum(debits)/len(debits)} for id_, debits in d.items()]
Out[24]: 
[{'userID': '1acv', 'Total Debits': 8000, 'Avg Debit': 2666.6666666666665},
 {'userID': '1acv', 'Total Debits': 2500, 'Avg Debit': 833.3333333333334}]
```

But this may not be the most efficient way when you're dealing with very larger data sets. In order to avoid doing `sum(debits)` two times you may want to use another constructor like `int` for the `defaultdict` instead of list and preserve the sum of `debits` and the number of items for each user id.

Comment: Actually there are 60+ variable in `js`(not only `debit`). So will I have to append `i['value']` with every variable that i have? is there any other way to solve this?

Comment: what's `i['value']`?

Comment: `d[i['userID']].append(i['debit'])` Instead of `debit` i wrote `value` to interpret 60+ variables

Comment: Doesn't make any difference, you can use this approach but if you ever needed a faster solution or your were not satisfied with the current performance you can do what I said.